# Hard drive not visible while dual booting Xubuntu on a Pentium 5 Windows 7 machine

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive, 32-bit, acpi, sata

Using a Pentium 5 Windows 7 machine. Further details are as follows:

> Processor: Intel(R) Pentium(R) Dual CPU E220 @ 2.20GHz 2.20GHz
> Installed Memory (RAM): 2GB
> System type: 32-bit Operating System

While dual booting Xububntu, the installation doesn't show the harddrive. Tried `fdisk -l` and using `gparted` but except the USB (installation media) no other harddrive is visible.

After reading number of forums and similar questions, got to know about AHCPI and RAID. Going through BIOS setup the only harddrive that the system has is connected to SATA 4. After changing the IDE configuration to COMPATIBLE the harddrive was showing against the SECONDARY SLAVE IDE.
Also, enabled AHCPI 2.0 but no luck.

Why the harddrive is not visible while installing Xubuntu? And how to resolve this issue.
Images:

[No hard drive found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Sc1C.jpg)

[Error when booting with USB with Xubuntu ISO made with Rufus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FI4sX.jpg)

Thank you.

**Edit**: The harddrive along with the partitions did show up once. I don't know how. But that was just once

Comment: For reference purposes: What brand and model is your motherboard? What does your BIOS say about itself (BIOS version, BIOS brand [ex. PheonixBIOS]) Also, what version AHCPI is your device? If it is higher than 2.0 (which it may be) AHCPI 2.0 will not work. If this is the case, perhaps try upgrading your BIOS.

Comment: @Jeff BIOS Brand: American Megatrends Inc. 0401, 6/20/2008

Comment: @Jeff I'm sorry but I can't find the version of AHCPI. Tried looking for it in device manager.

Comment: Please check the BIOS itself and try to find your drive. If not recognized there then it won't be for the installer, obviously. And yes, AHCI is usually preferable but for such old hardware there's nothing wrong with using IDE, it's just slower, but overall it won't make any noticeable difference. Of course, also update BIOS to the latest version published (if you still can find it),

Comment: Also make sure you prepared the drive from Windows by shrink the Windows partition to have unallocated space for Ubuntu. Furthermore **Windows 7 shouldn't be used** now, online, under NO circumstance because it's out of support for a long time already.

Comment: Make sure the hard drive cables are plugged in the correct slots on the board.

Comment: I used to use an Acer Aspire 5520 laptop (what a brick), dual booted with Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 7 (originally had Windows Vista). I had upgraded the RAM to 4GB, and the HDD to 500GB. It was slow, and only supported IDE. Ubuntu worked well, although startup was slow. It had PheonisBIOS, and it was outdated, couldn't flash an update. It still worked. In other words, do what ChanganAuto suggested and use IDE instead of AHCPI. That is what I recommend.